# Dropdown - Check if open using "isActive" property

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Relevant bootstrap.js code:

```
...
Dropdown.prototype = {

  constructor: Dropdown

  , toggle: function (e) {
     var $this = $(this)
     , $parent
     , isActive

  $parent = getParent($this)

  isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')
  ....
```

Is there a way to check for an open dropdown using *isActive* in a oneliner jquery like:

```
if($('#dropdownElement').isActive)
```

I know I can do something like:

```
var parent = $('#aParentID');
if(parent.hasClass('open')) { ...
```

But I wonder if I'm able to do it that way, thanks.

Comment: you can write is as a plugin, if you want

Comment: There's `is` too: `if ($('#parent').is('.open'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a one liner, then write it as a plugin

```
(function($){
    $.fn.isActive = function(){
        console.log(this)
        return $(this.get(0)).hasClass('open')
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Then

```
$('#dropdownElement').isActive()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kC4Rc/1/)

Comment: Yea, pretty fly, thank you. But what's the point of the dropdown object to have that 'isActive' property if we can't access it? I mean, probably there's a way to, and that's what I'm looking for

Comment: @AntonioMax as far as I can see, it is a local variable inside the bootstrap methods, so there is no way to access it directly

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution did not work for me. I was using Bootstrap 4, maybe something has changed. I digged into `dropdown.js` code and I found this:

```
const ClassName = {
  ...
  SHOW      : 'show',
  ...
}
...
toggle() {
   ...
   const isActive = $(this._menu).hasClass(ClassName.SHOW)
   ...
}
```

So the solution for me was:

```
var isShown = document.getElementById('dropdownElement').classList.contains('show');
```

Using jQuery, that'd be:

```
var isShown = $("#dropdownElement").hasClass("show");
```

Comment: For anyone using Bootstrap 3 instead, use .hasClass("open") instead of hasClass("show")

Comment: Note that bootstrap doesn't clear class `open` from the html attribut